# New photo/video loop app seen on instagram, what is it called?

Tags: software, photo-editing, iphone, instagram

I saw an brand new iPhone (possibly Android too) Video/Photo app when I was browsing Instagram. Unfortunately I didn't like any of their pictures or their instagram promo page for the app.

The app brand and name was a short one liner name/logo. Their logo/branding was very clean and cool. I think the logo had lilac colour in it.

What the app does is even better and unique, but I cannot find it anywhere on google or the app store. The results are very impressive.

The output is a perfectly still image, but the image is a video loop. And video is only a certain section of the photo.

So imagine a perfectly still photo, but part of the photo is a moving video, and in a continuous loop, the image/video-loop outputs are quite cereal.

There is also a posibility that this app only pushes to instagram.

> If anyone knows what this app is called, would be great to know and
>   use it.
>
> Many Thanks

Comment: do you mean boomerang? where u can take a really short video and its constantly on a loop (like a gif).

Comment: Nope not boomerang, the video is a complete still frame, and this app that i'm talking about must have some way of adding a video to the still but partially cropping the video. I'm going to try a replicate the output using some video software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you say its not Boomerang than my guess is you're referring to [Flixel](http://www.flixel.com). It's a software application that's a little costly but really cool. You can do the same effects in Photoshop or After Effects with a bit more effort though. That's how I make Cinemagraphs as they've come to be known.

On Instagram: https://www.instagram.com/flixelphotos/

Or Hashtag Flixel: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/flixel/

Hashtag Cineamgraph: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/cinemagraph/

Here's a tutorial to make it in Photoshop, there's lots of others: http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-make-a-cool-cinemagraph-image-in-photoshop

Basically Flixel just helps you mask part of your video and loop it for you. I've done them in Photoshop and Premier. I find Premier to be the easiest. Just find a part you like, trim, duplicate, and reverse the time on the second part to -100 and you can get it pretty good with very little effort. Then can always save a frame and auto-import it to your scene and mask out parts you need to remain static.

I've run ad campaigns using them and absolutely see higher conversation rate from them.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but no is not Boomerang, I know this one. Its newer and I don't think it's instagram related, but would surprise me if instagram buys them out, it's that good. I'm going to try and replicate the output using Adobe Premiere.

Comment: @joshmoto I think you mean Flixel then. I edited my answer for you

Comment: Yes! It is Flixel! Perfect thank you dude!!! I could not find this for love nor money, appreciate you help alot!!!

Answer (score 1):

The photo/video is called cinemagraph. There are many applications or tutorials on the internet how to make it. But I like using GIMP. It is image editing software like photoshop but free. So you can use it without purchasing it first. It can produce good quality of cinemagraph even HD.

Here is cinemagraph tutorial using GIMP : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSNj50T4knE&list=PL_5jFPphnJalcQsS1z2OIXRmPajnWvw86